# Css file not loading using Express JS backend on react project

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express

Before asking this question I researched around SO and found a few things but one of them worked in my scenario. I'm trying to load my React website from an Express backend server.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
client
  build
    css
      styles.css
    index.html
server
  server.js
```

I'm just trialing and experimenting with express right now mainly to learn a bit more about it and my `server.js` file looks like this

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require("path");

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.json({"users": ["userOne", "userTwo"]})
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "client", "build")));
app.use(express.static("../client/public"));

app.listen(5000, () => console.log("server started on port 5000"))
```

My `index.html` head

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="./images/logo.png" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link type="css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
  <meta name="description" content="Welcome to Sintra Welcome Centre" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/master/jquery.ddslick.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
```

When I run the server on port 5000 I can see the HTML being loaded up fine but I can't see any reference to the styles.css file anywhere, checking on the network tab it seems it isn't being loaded at all.

Can anyone spot my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The markup validator](https://validator.nu/) would have picked up this error if you had used it.

> ```
>   <link type="css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
> ```

The only MIME type browsers recognise for CSS is `text/css`.

You've told it to expect `css` (which isn't a valid MIME type anyway) so the browser believes it can't use the stylesheet because it isn't in a known format.

Consequently it doesn't try to load it.

Omit the `type` attribute.